# Set Bullet char on SQLite field VARCHAR

Tags: java, android, special-characters, settext

I want to be able to set special chars like a bullet ( • ) in my VARCHAR field (SQLite) where I got a text description. So that I will be able to use it later on my textView.setText.

Is there like a special character sequence which I can use? 
Like -&-b-u-l-l-;- in HTML?

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I found out the answer myself with the help of an answer that was given here (for some reason the user deleted his answer). :(

I set my field to NVARCHAR from VARCHAR that it was. (This was the main trick thanks to that guy)
And then use this \u2022 to represent the bullet in my text.

Thanks :)